# Is the $r$-axis in spherical coordinates the same as the $z$-axis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

If Cartesian coordinates have an $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and $z$-axis, do spherical coordinates have an $r$-axis, a $\theta$-axis, and a $\phi$-axis?

Since the Cartesian $z$-axis is just the set:

$$\{(0, 0, z) \mid z \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

I assume that the $r$-axis would be the set:

$$\{(r, 0, 0) \mid r \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

although I guess we have to stipulate $r \ge 0$. How to picture this? Since $\phi = 0$, we'd be pointing straight up, so that leads me to think that the $r$-axis in spherical coordinates is (half) the $z$-axis in Cartesian coordinates. Is this correct?

What about the $\theta$-axis and the $\phi$-axis? I want to picture the first as a circle in the $xy$-plane, but since $r = 0$ maybe it would just all collapse to zero. Likewise for $\phi$ -- I want to see it as an arc extending from the North Pole to the South Pole, but again $r = 0$.

Does "the set of all points where all but coordinate $c$ are zero" suffice as a description of $c$-axis? **Are there coordinate systems with axes that aren't linear subspaces?** (I thought spherical or polar would do this, but I seem to have failed!)

Comment: Picture the point lying on a sphere with center in the origin. The coordinate $r$ represents the radius of that sphere and the angles represent roughly the longitude and latitude on the sphere. [Compare with this image](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/images/sphpol.gif). So, $r$ does not represent a location in a fixed axis, but rather represents the position of the point along a ray that starts at the origin and points towards the (3d) direction determined by the two angles.

Comment: Check http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phz3113/notes/week7.pdf

Comment: Introducing spherical coordinates means introducing an "auxiliary" or "virtual" $(r,\phi,\theta)$-space in which, e.g., integrations are performed. Usually this auxiliary space is not drawn in a separate figure. Instead the meanings of $r$, $\phi$, $\theta$ are indicated in the main $(x,y,z)$-figure, and one exhibits the the relevant transformation formulas.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Right -- we don't usually draw the figure for the "spherical" space. But suppose we did. I guess another way to phrase the question is: do all coordinate systems have things which can be called "axes"? When are these axes linear subspaces, and when are they not?